# Redirect to *New Page* on scroll - how to add time delay?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, scroll, settimeout

very new to jquery here. I found a super helpful note by a user on how to redirect the user to a new page once they have scrolled to the bottom of the original page with the following code:

```
$(window).scroll(function() {


if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) window.location = "page2.html";
});
```

However, I'd like the function to delay for about 2 seconds so the transition isn't so jarring. I've tried to implement setTimeout, but still don't have a solid grasp on jQuery syntax/language to figure it out. Would love any help, thank you!

Comment: Where is your attempt at using `setTimeout` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Was setTimeout in the $(document).ready(...) script?

It should work...
Try:

```
setTimeout(
function() 
{
if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) 
window.location = "page2.html";
}, 2000);
```